# How to execute floor division in Python code embedded in Rust code with PyO3?

Tags: rust, pyo3

I'm trying to inline Python code in Rust, but it fails when the Python code has the operator for floor division `//` which is ignored as if it were a Rust comment.

For instance:

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene)]
use inline_python::python;

fn main() {
    python! {
        print("Hi from PyO3")
        foo = 37.46 // 3
        print(foo)
    }
}
```

This will print `37.46` even though it should print `12.0` (the result of floor division of 37.46 by 3).

A possible solution is to replace this division by `foo = math.floor(37.43 / 3)`, but I would prefer not to have to modify the Python code if possible. I'm also afraid it might impact performance.

Is there a way to use the floor division operator (or equivalent) in Python code embedded in Rust code with PyO3?

Comment: The `//` operator desugars to `47.46.__floordiv__ (3)` so at least you can be sure that this won't affect performance. It still requires modifying your Python code though…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.rs/inline-python/0.4.0/inline_python/#syntax-issues):

> The // and //= operators are unusable, as they start a comment.
>
> Workaround: you can write ## instead, which is automatically converted to //.

So try

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene)]
use inline_python::python;

fn main() {
    python! {
        print("Hi from PyO3")
        foo = 37.46 ## 3
        print(foo)
    }
}
```